# Kendo autocomplete asp.net undefined value

Tags: asp.net, razor, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete (asp.net core)

Razor view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
          .Name("users")
          .Filter("startswith")
          .Placeholder("Type user name...")
          .DataTextField("Email")
          .Events(e =>
          {
              e.Select("onSelect");
          })
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetUsers", "User").Data("onAdditionalData");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:30%" })
          .MinLength(2)
          .Suggest(true)
          .Height(400)
      .Template("<span class=\"k-state-default\">\\#=users.Email\\#</span>"))
```

Server side:

```
     [HttpGet]
        public dynamic GetUsers(string term)
        {
            return ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Email.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
.Select(res => new { id = res.Id.ToString(), name = res.Email }).ToList();            
        }
```

In my view I always get right number of value, but it is always "undefined". Where I`m wrong?

Comment: Please add an example of the ajax request's data. You can see it in the Dev Tools(F12) in Network Tab.

Comment: Where are you returning the 'Email' entity from the Action 'GetUsers' that you have mentioned in the Autocomplete `.DataTextField("Email")`? OR use  `.DataTextField("name")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are renaming "Email" to "name" in your server-side action; So you should use

```
.DataTextField("name")
```